# Messy selection loop

Tags: c++

I'm a beginner programmer and I'm trying to make a simple 2D Space Game in C++ using SplashKit's Library.
I'm trying to make a selection loop using IF - Else to check if the planet has been visited or not.
But, I think it's too messy and not good. Any help to make it simpler would be nice :)

```
        // Draws the Scoreboard and check if the planet is visited or not
        if ( planet[0].visited == true)
        {
            draw_hud(player, planet[0]);
        }
        else if ( planet[1]. visited == true)
        {
            draw_hud(player, planet[1]);
        }
        else if ( planet[2]. visited == true)
        {
            draw_hud(player, planet[2]);
        }
        else if ( planet[3]. visited == true)
        {
            draw_hud(player, planet[3]);
        }
        else if ( planet[4]. visited == true)
        {
            draw_hud(player, planet[4]);
        }
        else if ( planet[5]. visited == true)
        {
            draw_hud(player, planet[5]);
        }
        else if ( planet[6]. visited == true)
        {
            draw_hud(player, planet[6]);
        }
        else if ( planet[7]. visited == true)
        {
            draw_hud(player, planet[7]);
        }
        else if ( planet[8]. visited == true)
        {
            draw_hud(player, planet[8]);
        }
        else 
        {
            draw_hud(player, planet[9]);
        }
```

Comment: Don't compare booleans to `true` or `false`. They already are one or the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Look up [for loops](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/63-arrays-and-loops/)
- You don't need to specify == true. You can simply omit it and read it in your mind like "if this is true". (For false you would do if (!planet[i].visited) ).

That entire block of code becomes:

```cpp
for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    if (planet[i].visited) {
        draw_hud(player,planet[i]);
    }
}
```

Also check out codereview stack exchange, its more dedicated to these types of questions.

Comment: @JonathanVieri just FYI, the "for" implementation is not completely equivalent to the original code. The original code will only draw one hud, whereas the for loop could potentially draw one for each planet the player has visited. If the hud should be drawn for only the first visited planet, add a break to the if statement.

Comment: No need for i in the loop

Comment: @Kei And also if got to i == 9, it draws unconditionally

Comment: @KennyOstrom can you elaborate?

Comment: And also the condition check is invalid. Should be `if(planet[i].visited)` rather than `if(player[i].visited)`

Comment: Thanks guys for all the useful information and help :), i managed to finish it ^_^

Comment: many languages, including python, let you loop with a variable that has each instance from the collection, without needing an index. It just gets the item from the collection for you so that within the loop you can focus on the task at hand.

Comment: Good point, Java has this `for (Player p : Players)`  @Digionix see if you want to use that instead of indexes.